# Different results for css-masonry and ellipsis on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, masonry, ellipsis

I am using masonry grid layout using `column-count` on the parent div and I am trying to add ellipsis to the paragraph in the child if it exceeds more than 4 lines using `-webkit-line-clamp`.

I am not concerned about non-webkit browsers at the moment but about getting different results on chrome and safari. (Both using webkit as web browser engine).

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Safari:**

[image]

I was expecting similar behaviour on both but with `max-height` and `overflow: hidden` set on paragraph, the parent div on safari is still taking the height of the entire content.

[image]

Commented `overflow:hidden` and gave a `background-color` for clear understanding.

**I found** that it works fine without `column-count` or in my case without `masonry` class.

Is there any solution to this problem? Or do I have to rely on plugins for masonry and ellipsis?

**Here's the code:**

```css
        body{
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            margin: 30px;
            font-size: 1.05rem;
        }

        .card{
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 25px; 
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        .masonry{
            column-count: 3;
            column-width: 220px;
            -webkit-column-count: 3;
            -moz-column-count: 3;
            -webkit-column-width: 220px;
            -moz-column-width: 220px;
            column-gap: 25px;
        }

        .masonry div{
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .card-body p{
            overflow: hidden;
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            max-height: 6em;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `.card-body{overflow:hidden}` may solve the problem

Comment: Whoa! It did work. Thanks!